# Can't access ssh in my VM Centos

Tags: ssh, centos, virtualbox, ip

My Centos's IP is diferent of the normal.

And I can't access it in a ssh command [image: see here]

And when I tried access using ssh noting [image: see here]

I want to use ssh and samba client, but my IP is diferent.

And I have install Centos in my other VM in a diferent Ubuntu, but the IP appear the same 10.0.2.15

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on how you configured your network interfaces. I would check in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0` on the new VM and see if you can just change the value for `IPADDR` if it's present. If you have `NetworkManager` running and the interface is configured with `NM_CONTROLLED=yes` then the change will be applied when you save the file, otherwise you'll have to do a `service network restart` to make the change effective.

Comment: Ok @Joel Davis, but see my ifcfg-eth0 [link]http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/captura_de_tela_de_2014-03-26_12_12_32-png

Comment: You're coming off DHCP, which means it's the DHCP server that is giving the same IP address out, probably because the MAC address didn't change when you cloned. I'd change the MAC at the VirtualBox and RHEL (in that same file) levels and then reboot.

Comment: Right @Joel Davis. But how can I change the MAC at the VirtualBox and RHEL?

Comment: Change the MAC Address in the file you showed me to take care of RHEL and in VirtualBox: `VirtualBox Main Manager -> guest settings -> networking -> advanced`

Comment: when I tried to connect using ssh appear the message "Connection refused" or "No route to host" even than I change the port, noting change. See link http://uploaddeimagens.com.br/imagens/captura_de_tela_de_2014-04-01_12_43_29-png

Answer (score 26):

This looks like you're using VirtualBox VM with a NAT network (it seems to give the address 10.0.2.15 by default). If so, you need to set up a port forward to access port 22 on the VM from the host.

1. Open Settings->Network for the VM
2. Click the little blue arrow next to the Advanced box
3. Click the box at the bottom labelled "Port Forwarding"
4. Click the green "+" to add a rule
5. Add the rule Host IP="127.0.0.1", Host Port="2222", Guest IP="10.0.2.15", Guest Port="22"
6. From the host, you should be able to "ssh -p2222 127.0.0.1"

This is a bit stupid compared to the way VMWare does NAT. It creates a separate network interface on the host for NAT, so no forwarding is necessary.

Comment: ok, but when I do rhis, can I make a ssh and samba client connection?

Comment: Yes, you can. And this should be the accepted answer. (Commenting for future readers, since OP posted over 2 years ago.)

Comment: To back up @dr01, I just used this answer to fix the same issue.  I'm using a CentOS 7 guest on a Win7 host.

Comment: This worked for me.

Comment: Worked for me too. In Ubuntu I didn't have to specify the IP