# Is it okay if both your linux VM's have the IP Address

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

[image: My VM's have the some IP]

what do you do when you VM's have the same ip

Comment: Give them a different IP.

Comment: If they are in the same network, no, they cannot have the same IP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't access ssh in my VM Centos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/121588/cant-access-ssh-in-my-vm-centos)

Answer (score 2):

It is not OK to have two VMs with identical IP addresses on the same subnet. This can be caused by:

Selecting "`I moved`" instead of "`I copied`" when importing a VM. When you "move" a VM, its MAC address is preserved. When you import the same VM twice with a "move" option, the two VMs will have an identical MAC address. To fix this, you must re-generate MAC addresses on each VM.

When you clone a VM, make sure that you perform a "full" clone so that VM1 is independent to VM2

Answer (score 0):

That's an ip address from the private address range 10.0.0.0/8. Everybody can use them within their local or virtual network, and so can VirtualBox. It's just like my neighbor and I can both have 192.168.178.1 in our wi-fi networks.

Outgoing connections from those VMs will be NATed so there's no confusion, and if you want to make services on those machines available to you will need to map them to host ports.

Of course, you can also use non-NAT networking options, for example assign separate IP addresses to the machines statically or via DHCP.

Your best move might be to read the VirtualBox documentation on networking :-)

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: Keep in mind with this answer, it is ok if two VMs **not on the same virtual subnet** to have the same IP.  If they’re connected to the same virtual subnet, it won’t work.